# Java AES-ECB-NoPadding not accepting string≠*16 bytes, but Javascript does, why?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptojs

**Question:** Using Java*script* and CryptoJS, AES-ECB-ZeroPadding, a key of 16 bytes and a string (to encrypt) of 7 bytes does not produce any errors, but in Java it **does**, why?

*Question #2:* How to update the Java code so it can decrypt / encrypt from Javascript (Java is the slave, Javascript is the master I won't to copy from...)

!

--- *See below* #1 Java sample code producing the error
--- #2 Javascript sample NOT producing the error with same key, string and encryption method

Java error:

```
Error while encrypting: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 16 bytes
```

Sample script in Java:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AES {

  private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
  private static byte[] key;

  public static void setKey(final String myKey) {
    MessageDigest sha = null;
    try {
      key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
      sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
      key = sha.digest(key);
      key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
      secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static String encrypt(final String strToEncrypt, final String secret) {
    try {
      setKey(secret);
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
      return Base64.getEncoder()
        .encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static String decrypt(final String strToDecrypt, final String secret) {
    try {
      setKey(secret);
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
      return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder()
        .decode(strToDecrypt)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

**credit for Java script: http://www.java2s.com/example/java/security/aes-decrypt-with-cipher-mode-aesecbnopadding.html (slightly altered)*

Sample script in Javascript (using CryptoJS 4.1.1)

```js
var stringKey = document.getElementById('key').value;
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(stringKey);
document.getElementById('keylength').value = stringKey.length;

var inputText = document.getElementById('input').value;
document.getElementById('inputlength').value = inputText.length;

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(inputText, key, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding }); 

encrypted = encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex).toUpperCase();

document.getElementById('encrypted').value = encrypted;
document.getElementById('encryptedlength').value = encrypted.length;

var decrypted =  CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encrypted)}, key, {mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding });

decrypted = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
document.getElementById('decrypted').value = decrypted;
```

```css
html, body { font-family: Helvetica; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/aes.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/enc-hex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/md5.min.js"></script>



CryptoJS 4.1.1 / AES, ECB, ZeroPadding.
<hr>
<br>
string to encrypt:
<input id="input" value="test_12">
length: 
<input id="inputlength" value="">
<hr>
<br>
key:
<input id="key" value="3F58157108A30139BAD539861614DAC2">
length: 
<input id="keylength" value="">
<hr>
<br>
encrypted:
<input id="encrypted">
length: 
<input id="encryptedlength" value="">
<hr>
<br>
decrypted:
<input id="decrypted">
```

Comment: There is no contradiction. ECB is a block cipher mode, i.e. the plaintext size must be an integer multiple of the block size (16 bytes for AES). A 7 bytes plaintext does not meet the length criterion, so padding is required. Since padding is not performed on the Java side (`NoPadding`), an exception is thrown during encryption. On the JavaScript side, however, padding is applied (`ZeroPadding `), which is why encryption works.

Comment: Ah!!! First of, thank you very much for the tip!  ...ZeroPadding is not the same as NoPadding, I did not realize that. I found the appropriate Java equivalent "ZeroBytePadding" and am testing it now.

Comment: More reliable than Zero Padding is PKCS7 Padding! Besides the padding, both codes differ regarding the key derivation. But before you tediously match the codes, you should rethink your concept. ECB is insecure, use a mode with IV (e.g. CBC) or even better authenticated encryption (e.g. GCM). If your key material is a string apply a key derivation function (at least PBKDF2) in combination with a salt. For each encryption a random IV and salt must be created.

Comment: It seems "AES/ECB/ZeroBytePadding" does not exists (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) hence I would be required to add / remove 0s for it to match a multiple of 16 bytes myself. Secondly ...unfortunately for me, this is the client requirement (AES/ECB/ZeroPadding) as is the Javascript example I have given ...I don't have the luxury to offer / create my own encryption method in this case, I do appreciate the input though.